# How can I get the value of "%d" variables in dynamic_debug info of Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel, kernel-module

I enabled `config_dynamic_debug=y` in the Linux kernel customized by myself, and following the dynamic_debug documentation shipped with kernel source code, I run the following command to enable the output of the debug information in bluetooth subsystem:

```
echo -n 'file net/bluetooth/bnep/core.c line 722 +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

which means the debug info in the line 772 of the file `net/bluetooth/bnep/core.c` will be logged.

After the bnep.ko module is loaded, I checked the output of `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`, the debug information is there.

But most of them look like:

```
> net/bluetooth/bnep/core.c:422 [bnep]bnep_tx_frame - "skb %p dev %p type %d\012"
```

I really want to know the value represented by `%p` or `%d`, but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have enabled that debug statement, which is what reading from `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control` tells you.

From now on, that debug message will be sent to the normal kernel log, which you can view with `dmesg` and/or with your syslog daemon (which will normally log to `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/everything/`, or some similar path).

Comment: You are right. I can find the output in "/var/log/messages", thank you very much!